# MsDeploy commands not working

Tags: iis

We are currently planning to migrate IIS 6 applications (hosted in Windows 2003) to IIS 8 on Windows 2012. We followed Microsoft instructions for using their provided tool MSDEPLOY and configured at both source as well as destination ends, but when we perform commands provided in the guide we get the below error

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy>msdeploy -verb:sync  -source:metakey=l m/w3svc/1 -dest:package=c:\Site1.zip > WebDeployPackage.log
```

> 'msdeploy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Note: we have followed the instructions at http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above to configure MS-Deploy tool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you installed web deploy with complete option selected?
If yes, then change path in command to and try. For me it is working from below path

C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\

Comment: Superb That worked for me .. do you have entire step-by-step(screen shot) process to migrate applications from windows 2003 to windows 2012 , it would be great help if anyone has it .

Comment: @vikas The underlying configuration architecture of IIS 8 is the same as IIS 7.x, the guide you already have should suffice. If this answer solves your problem, mark it as such (click the tick mark below the vote count on the left)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and it turns out that i was migrating with WebDeploy3.5 on windows server 2008 and on Windows Server 2012 WebDeploy version was 3.6, when i matched the exact same versions then issue resolved.